# How to sort array of repeated object keys day values and create a new array with object coordinates where y will hold the value of repetitions

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, iteration

Iterating the dates array to create a new array with the following format

```
 const dates= [
          {datetime:'Monday'},
          {datetime:'Tuesday'},
          {datetime:'Wednesday'},
          {datetime:'Thursday'},
          {datetime:'Monday'},
          {datetime:'Wednesday'},
          {datetime:'Friday'},
          {datetime:'Monday'}]
        // Result 
   result = [ { x: 'Monday', y: 3 },
   { x: 'Tuesday', y: 1 },
   { x: 'Wednesday', y: 2 },
   { x: 'Thursday', y: 1 },
   { x: 'Friday', y: 1 } ]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be great if you could post whatever code you used to attemp solving this problem, so any help would be very surgical (and easier)

Answer (score 0):

You could group and count by date then transform it to array of your expectation with `map`

```js
const dates = [
  { datetime: "Monday" },
  { datetime: "Tuesday" },
  { datetime: "Wednesday" },
  { datetime: "Thursday" },
  { datetime: "Monday" },
  { datetime: "Wednesday" },
  { datetime: "Friday" },
  { datetime: "Monday" },
];

const groupByDatetime = dates.reduce((acc, el) => {
  acc[el.datetime] = (acc[el.datetime] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

const res = Object.entries(groupByDatetime).map(([datetime, count]) => ({
  x: datetime,
  y: count,
}));

console.log(res);
```

[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is called grouping.

#### Idea

- Create an object that will hold key(day) and its count
- Loop over your data and update the count
- At the end, loop over this object and create the final format you need

```js
const dates= [
  {datetime:'Monday'},
  {datetime:'Tuesday'},
  {datetime:'Wednesday'},
  {datetime:'Thursday'},
  {datetime:'Monday'},
  {datetime:'Wednesday'},
  {datetime:'Friday'},
  {datetime:'Monday'}]
const map = dates.reduce((map, item) => {
  map[ item.datetime ] = (map[ item.datetime ] || 0) + 1
  return map
}, {});

const result = Object.keys(map).map((key) => ({ x: key, y: map[key] }))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the relatively new `Array.flat()` method to enable the grouping and mapping all in one map.

```
const dates= [
  {datetime:'Monday'},
  {datetime:'Tuesday'},
  {datetime:'Wednesday'},
  {datetime:'Thursday'},
  {datetime:'Monday'},
  {datetime:'Wednesday'},
  {datetime:'Friday'},
  {datetime:'Monday'}
]

dates.map((d1, i) => {
  if (i === dates.findIndex(d2 => d2.datetime === d1.datetime)) {
    return [{
      x: d1.datetime,
      y: dates.filter(d2 => d2.datetime === d1.datetime).length
    }]
  } else {
    return []
  }
})
.flat()
```

The performance is definitely worse that an `Array.reduce()` approach. I'm not sure about other considerations though.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var dates2 = [
  { datetime: 'Monday' },
  { datetime: 'Tuesday' },
  { datetime: 'Wednesday' },
  { datetime: 'Thursday' },
  { datetime: 'Monday' },
  { datetime: 'Wednesday' },
  { datetime: 'Friday' },
  { datetime: 'Monday' }
]

var result = dates2.reduce((a, c) => {
  let entry = a.find(e => e.x == c.datetime);
  if (entry) ++entry.y;
  else a.push({
    x: c.datetime,
    y: 1
  });
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result );
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through the items, and build an object with `key` as datetime.
when same datetime occur, increment values

```js
const combine = (arr, all = {}) => {
  arr.forEach(({ datetime: x }) => ((all[x] ??= { x, y: 0 }).y += 1));
  return Object.values(all);
};

const dates = [
  { datetime: "Monday" },
  { datetime: "Tuesday" },
  { datetime: "Wednesday" },
  { datetime: "Thursday" },
  { datetime: "Monday" },
  { datetime: "Wednesday" },
  { datetime: "Friday" },
  { datetime: "Monday" },
];

console.log(combine(dates))
```